# Flash on the grid

Tags: mesh

The problem is that when I turn on edit mod, I see flashes on my model, and later, in these areas when exporting the model, I observe problems with uvmap scanning. Do you know what the problem might be?
[image: Text]
[image: Text]
[image: Text]

Comment: Wrong UV? Select the problematic face and check UV map in UV editor. It looks like if it is not completely wrong rotate it 90 °

Comment: @vklidu but why, if the texture lies flat and only in places these damn lights?

Comment: Brighter color in edit mode can be indicator of face normal direction, that is pointed in opposite direction than others. Search for that ... but I thought your main issue is last image with squeezed texture at that place, so my first comment was pointing to that.

Answer (score 0):

The whole problem was in the second UV map.
In object data properties (green triangle), smart UV has created a second layer. By deleting one of the previous ones, the problem disappeared.